# help me to run stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have a stepper motor ( Model = 23KM-K381-01V , NO.T6Z23-07 , DWG NO.56AA80112).

**Motor Specifications:**

Motor is unipolar , 6Wires , 2A current , 1.8 deg step angle.. 
Motor is second hand.
I do not have datasheet of the motor.
and the worst thing is no wire is connected to the motor. so I can not take benefit of color coding.

So my question is how do I know that which wire of the motor should be connected to A+ , A- , B+ , B- of the stepper motor driver...

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I found it here https://www.eminebea.com/en/product/rotary/steppingmotor/hybrid/standard/23km-k.shtml. With 4 power FETs 12V to Com-A and B then there are are 4 phases using only one A coil switch and B switch to ground . But best solution is a Arduino CNC bridge and GCODE panel GUI on windows

Comment: lol .... i only got as far as determining that it is a Minolta paper exit drive motor

Comment: This is how the wiring setup is present in the link provided by you:  6-Lead Wire. A+ | A Common | A - | B + | B Common | B - .           So how do I know A+ is on which side (left or right) of the motor ???

Comment: A six wire motor is not unipolar, it's able to be used as *either* bipolar or unipolar.

Comment: Remember to upvote and accept an answer

Comment: yes after reading , I came to know that we can use a  6 wire motor in either unipolar and bipolar modes.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the four windings by measuring resistance. Resistance of L1-to-centre-tap will equal resistance of L2-to-centre-tap. (And resistance of L3-to-centre-tap will equal resistance of L4-to-centre tap). All terminals of L1/L2 have infinite resistance to all terminals of L3/L4.
 Six-wire stepper test circuit can go like this. Use a low-voltage DC source that doesn't heat the motor coils when one of the four switches are closed.:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT4xG9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A typical 4-step sequence might be:

1. SW1:**closed**, SW2:open, SW3:open, SW4:open
2. SW1:open, SW2:open, SW3:**closed**, SW4:open
3. SW1:open, SW2:**closed**, SW3:open, SW4:open
4. SW1:open, SW2:open, SW3:open, SW4:**closed**

There are other step-sequence possibilities than this one. At each step, check which way the stepper rotates. You should be able to arrange the coils so that the sequence steps always clockwise.

Comment: okay I will test like this.

Answer (score 0):

Six wires are, almost certainly, two sets of three. Each set of three is respectively connected to a coil, and call them: minus, plus, and  center-tap. The DC resistance between any two wires from the same set of three should be very small. The resistance between two of the wires will be double that of any other two in the set of three, so you can use that to identify the center tap. Ground both center taps. There are four ways the polarity of the remaining pairs could be, but only one of them will make sense with your stepping sequence.  Brute force the possibilities.

Comment: You said:   "There are four ways the polarity of the remaining pairs could be, but only one of them will make sense with your stepping sequence.".....So should i try all those 4 sequences??? Don't you think a wrong sequence will damage my stepper motor driver???

Comment: No I think it just won't work if the sequence is incorrect. Unlikely to cause damage in my opinion.

Comment: But i was going through the datasheet of the stepper driver TB6560 (https://www.mpja.com/download/31306ms.pdf) and it was written "if motor is connected wrongly it may cause damage to driver"

Comment: Should i leave both center taps ?? Because i have seen a video in which the person didn't make use of the center tap.

Comment: Try giving this a read https://learn.adafruit.com/all-about-stepper-motors

Comment: Center taps are needed for a unipolar configuration and usually unconnected in a biploar one.  Your motor can support either.